# Elisp files in load-path are not loaded on emacs start

Tags: load-path

What failed for me?

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/others")
```

what worked for me?

```
(mapc 'load (file-expand-wildcards "~/.emacs.d/others/*.el"))
```

Functions defined in elisp files lying @`~/.emacs.d/others` were not loaded in the first case.

So, is it wrong to assume that adding folder paths to `load-path` will load the *.el files lying underneath?

Comment: Adding to the load path does not actually load any files. It only tells emacs where to look for files when you ask it to load them.

Comment: @Dan - That looks like answer to me

Comment: Using `load` is not a good approach. Better update the `load-path` as in the first snippet and then use `require` or `autoload` as necessary. Better yet check out the `use-package` package; it will help make loading the packages more efficient.

Comment: @kaushalmodi, `use-package` grants convenience while adding (small) overhead.
I don't know if that can be classified as loading packages more efficiently.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: have now posted a somewhat more detailed answer based on the comment.

Comment: @abo-abo Yes, that's correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding to the [`load-path`](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/LoadPath) does not actually load any files.  Instead, it only tells Emacs where to look for files when you ask it to load them.  As the docstring indicates:

> Documentation:
>
> **List of directories to search for files to load.**
>   Each element is a string (directory name) or `nil` (try default directory).
>   Initialized based on EMACSLOADPATH environment variable, if any,
>   otherwise to default specified by file `epaths.h` when Emacs was built.

As the other comments indicate, there are various ways to load elisp libraries and packages once they're on the `load-path`.  You can, for example, use [`load`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Loading-Files.html), [`autoload`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Autoload.html#Autoload), [`require`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Named-Features.html), and [`use-package`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package).